# Drupal 7: Cron claims webform module function to be undefined

Tags: webforms, cron

I cant really figure this out.

I have a module which interacts with the webform module which just works perfectly fine.

But now I wanted to create a cron which updates certain submissions, but the cron function claims that suddenly the webform function `webform_get_submission` is undefined although all other mymodule functions use webform functions without any issues. How come?

```
// a whole lot functions which use webform functions
// [...]

function mymmodule_cron() {
    $conf = mymmodule_defaults();

    // check cron run
    if(true /* for testing */){

        // set writable User
        global $user;
        $original_user = $user;
        $old_state = drupal_save_session(FALSE);
        $user = user_load(1);

        // fancy sql statement
        $sql = array();
        // [...]
        $sql = join(" ",$sql);
        $result = db_query($sql);

        $queue = DrupalQueue::get('mymmodule_cron_archiveanon');

        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $row->anon = true;
            $queue->createItem($row);           
        }      

        // restore default user
        $user = $original_user;
        drupal_save_session($old_state); 
    }

}

function mymmodule_cron_archiveanon_wrapper($item){
    $node = node_load($item->nid);

    if( function_exists('webform_get_submission')) {
        die("Yep."); 
        // $submission = webform_get_submission($item->nid, $item->sid);
    }
    else {
        die("Nope.");
        // dies here
    }

    // custom function
    // mymmodule_contract_archive($node, $submission, $item->anon);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function is in a file that isn't included by default; you just need to include it yourself:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
```

Comment: but why do the other webform functions work?

Comment: There aren't any other calls to webform functions in your code

Comment: i commented them out, see the very first line. within the cron function, there is not. so are you implying that i must, only for the cron function, include the module although all other hooks and function dont need to?

Comment: Not necessarily just the cron functions - if a file's not included in the context you're in, and you need a function within, you have to include it that's just PHP's way of splitting code into different files. I can't comment as to why some of the functions you're calling are available as you haven't mentioned which one's you're using, or what context you're calling them in

Comment: The context is that a webform form is opened, then all my functions get called and alter the webform. I will try out to include the file although I dont think this is an elegant solution! Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Right. But _what_ functions? Not all functions are in the same file, not every file is included in every page request. Hence the word "context". The above code is the correct, and only way to accomplish what you want. The only alternative you'll find is using PHP's own `include` or `require` functions. But since you're using Drupal the proper thing to do is use the Drupal APi, which is `module_load_include()`. I'm not sure why you'd think a single line of code makes things in-elegant

Comment: If you're still suspicious of `module_load_include()`, check [this page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/calls/module_load_include/7)...as you can see there are 46 calls to that function in core _alone_. If you look through some of the uses you'll see it's used in exactly the situation that you're describing. Hopefully that will convince you it's the correct function to use...cos you won't find a different way of doing it :)